# Sum the rows according to the columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I need to sum the values ​​of each hash line based on the keys.

In the example below, I need to add A with A, B with B, C with C, D with D of all rows and at the end return a single hash with the full value.

```
{adv=>{:a=>10, :b=>180, :c=>30, :d=>15}}

{adv=>{:a=>15, :b=>120, :c=>60, :d=>100}}

{adv=>{:a=>20, :b=>120, :c=>90, :d=>25}}
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [pt.so]?

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [
  {:adv=>{:a=>10, :b=>180, :c=>30, :d=>15}},
  {:adv=>{:a=>15, :b=>120, :c=>60, :d=>100}},
  {:adv=>{:a=>20, :b=>120, :c=>90, :d=>25}}
]

result = list.reduce do |memo, hsh|
  {
    adv: memo[:adv].merge(hsh[:adv]) do |key, val1, val2|
      val1 + val2
    end
  }
end

puts result
# => {:adv=>{:a=>45, :b=>420, :c=>180, :d=>140}}
```